# Angular 2 Organize AuthGuard(canActivate) and AuthService code

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

From my current code, when routing to a page with canActivate, I am able to achieve the authentication data from the server with the below

auth.guard.ts (version 1)

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', options )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((res) => {
                if (res.response) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I would want to to separate the code inside canActivate to auth.service.ts as below, but it is does not wait for the http request to finish and return

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    authenticate() :Observable<any>{
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', { options })
            .map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

auth.guard.ts (version 2)

```
    import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private http: Http) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if(this.authService.authenticate()){
            return true;
        }else{
            this.router.navigate(['/register])
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auth.guard.ts (version 3)

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private http: Http) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.authService.authenticate().map((res) => {
            if (res.response) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/register']);
                return false;
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Above code will chain your observables. But there's another problem with your code -- `if(res.response) {return true}`, when there's response, it could be 'user exists and logged in' or 'user does not exists'. So you are returning `true` for both cases. That you need fix.

Comment: I think you are missing a `return`; you're not returning the composed observable in `canActivate`.

Comment: i am having an error, incorrect implement interface 'CanActivate' with this changes

Comment: @cartant was right, with a return it fixed that error. Thanks!

Comment: Edited. Thanks @cartant